# Applying Gaussian blur on tensor in custom loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, convolution

I have a custom loss where I want to apply Gaussian filter to a predicted label to manipulate it a little. Using max or average pooling is simple as it is predefined in keras, but I had to make my own class for Gaussian pooling:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import DepthwiseConv2D
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model
import tensorflow as tf

class Gaussian():
    
    def __init__(self,shape, f = 3):
        self.filt = f
        self.g = self.gaussFilter(shape)
        
    def doFilter(self, data):
        return self.g.predict(data, steps=1) #steps are for predicting on const tensor, I change it when predicting on predictions 
    
    def gauss2D(self,shape=(3,3),sigma=0.5):
    
        m,n = [(ss-1.)/2. for ss in shape]
        y,x = np.ogrid[-m:m+1,-n:n+1]
        h = np.exp( -(x*x + y*y) / (2.*sigma*sigma) )
        h[ h < np.finfo(h.dtype).eps*h.max() ] = 0
        sumh = h.sum()
        if sumh != 0:
            h /= sumh
        return h
    
    def gaussFilter(self, size=256):
        kernel_weights = self.gauss2D(shape=(self.filt,self.filt))
        
        
        in_channels = 1  # the number of input channels
        kernel_weights = np.expand_dims(kernel_weights, axis=-1)
        kernel_weights = np.repeat(kernel_weights, in_channels, axis=-1) # apply the same filter on all the input channels
        kernel_weights = np.expand_dims(kernel_weights, axis=-1)  # for shape compatibility reasons
        
        
        inp = Input(shape=(size,size,1))
        g_layer = DepthwiseConv2D(self.filt, use_bias=False, padding='same')(inp)
        model_network = Model(input=inp, output=g_layer)
        print(model_network.summary())
        model_network.layers[1].set_weights([kernel_weights])
        model_network.trainable= False
            
        return model_network
```

This works as expected when feeding a constant tensor to the doFilter function, an example of simple data:

```
a = np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]])
filt = Gaussian(3)
print(filt.doFilter(tf.constant(a.reshape(1,3,3,1))))
```

However, if I try to use this in a custom loss :

```
def custom_loss_no_true(input_tensor, length):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        gaus_pooler = Gaussian(256, length//8)
        a = gaus_pooler.doFilter(y_pred)
        ...more stuff comes after
```

I get an error:

> ValueError: When feeding symbolic tensors to a model, we expect the
> tensors to have a static batch size. Got tensor with shape: (None,
> 256, 256, 1)

This is as I have found caused by the fact, that I am feeding a tensor that is an output of other model, a symbolic data, not actual values ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483198/keras-using-model-output-as-the-input-for-another-when-feeding-symbolic-tensor)). Thus I need to change the logic of my approach, because evaluating the tensor to feed my class would break the graph and lead to no gradient propagation within the loss (or am I incorrect?).  How can I apply such convolution operation on a tensor that is an output of other model? Is it even possible? Or maybe there is a way to use it without adding the layer to the model, such as MaxPooling?

Comment: You are using keras, then why not extend from `tf.keras.layers` rather than creating a whole new model for just one OP? See the guide : [Custom layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers)

Comment: @Lescurel I need to add the weights to the layer and got errors when it was not in a model, if I knew a better way I wouldn't ask :)

Comment: But you don't need the OP to be trainable apprently, so you could even do the calculation directly in Tensorflow, is that correct? The filter will not change during training.

Comment: will have to figure out how to do that and try it

Comment: I can probably come up with an answer doing that, if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a complex keras Model nor a keras Layer if what you want to do is just convolve your input with a Gaussian kernel. Here is a port of your code with simple tensorflow ops :

```py
import tensorflow as tf
def get_gaussian_kernel(shape=(3,3), sigma=0.5):
    """build the gaussain filter"""
    m,n = [(ss-1.)/2. for ss in shape]
    x = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(-n,n+1,dtype=tf.float32),1)
    y = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(-m,m+1,dtype=tf.float32),0)
    h = tf.exp(tf.math.divide_no_nan(-((x*x) + (y*y)), 2*sigma*sigma))
    h = tf.math.divide_no_nan(h,tf.reduce_sum(h))
    return h

def gaussian_blur(inp, shape=(3,3), sigma=0.5):
    """Convolve using tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d"""
    in_channel = tf.shape(inp)[-1]
    k = get_gaussian_kernel(shape,sigma)
    k = tf.expand_dims(k,axis=-1)
    k = tf.repeat(k,in_channel,axis=-1)
    k = tf.reshape(k, (*shape, in_channel, 1))
    # using padding same to preserve size (H,W) of the input
    conv = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(inp, k, strides=[1,1,1,1],padding="SAME")
    return conv
```

You can use it simply in your custom loss (assuming a 4D `y_pred` [batch, height width, channel]) :

```
a = gaussian_blur(y_pred)
```

Comment: great, it does the job, except that `tf.repeat` is not recognized, as I use lower tf version, but that is not problem as I have just one channel, thanks for help

Comment: You can use `k = tf.tile(k, (1,1,in_channel))` instead. Glad I could help.

Comment: further looking at this, the `get_gaussian_kernel` function works somehow incorrectly, filter consisted only from zeros and nans, couldn't find what is wrong so used my old numpy implementation and converted weights to tensor, all works right after that

Comment: This is weird, especially since I used `tf.math.divide_no_nan`. Out of interest, what parameters are you using for `shape` and `sigma`?

Comment: I used higher value for sigma but tried multiple and always got same result, 9x9 is shape, here is visualization of weights - [image](http://hs.4fan.cz/image_2020-12-10_150659.png), white space is nan ofc

Comment: I get [this image](https://i.imgur.com/Q9ERyvT.png) with `get_gaussian_kernel((9,9),1000)`. No Nan.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225777/discussion-between-lescurel-and-ruli).